# textrun error expression expected

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Hello I am running the following expression in a textbox and getting the error below.  I've used the same expression in other text boxes and it's working fine so am very confused as to why it's not working in this one.

```
=sum(IIF(Fields!Fieldname1.Value = "A" and Fields!Fieldname2.Value = "Red", Fields!Total.Value, Nothing)) / 1675 * 100 OR =sum(IIF(Fields!Fieldname1.Value = "A" and Fields!fieldname2.Value = "Blue", Fields!Total.Value, Nothing)) / 1702 * 100    

The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox278.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok managed to answer my own question, didn't need the '=' before the 'sum'

```
=sum(IIF(Fields!Fieldname1.Value = "Red" and Fields!Fieldname2.Value = "Red", Fields!Total.Value, Nothing)) / 1675 * 100 OR sum(IIF(Fields!Fieldname1.Value = "Blue" and Fields!Fieldname2.Value = "Blue", Fields!Total.Value, Nothing)) / 1702 * 100
```